# “Method 'Rows' of object '_Global' failed ” Error from Login upon startup

Tags: excel, performance, authentication, vba

I Need a bit of help with an excel program I'm creating. What I'm trying to do is create a login userform that when opening the excel in question, the login userform is the first thing to appear before having access to the workbook. Now when I test run the below code in VBA, it works no problem. However when I attempt to open the excel and login (how its suppose to function), it gives me the error that's in the title. This is the code:

`

```
    Sub LoginRun()
    Dim AddData As Range, Current As Range
    Dim user As Variant, Code As Variant
    Dim PName As Variant, AName As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim TitleStr As String
    Dim msg As VbMsgBoxResult

    'Variables
    user = OpeningWindow.UsernameTextbox.Value
    Code = OpeningWindow.PasswordTextbox.Value
    TitleStr = "Password check"
    result = 0
    Set Current = Sheet3.Range("B13")

    On Error GoTo errHandler:
    Set AddData = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    If user <> "" And Not IsNumeric(user) And Code <> "" And IsNumeric(Code) Then
        For Each AName In Sheet3.Range("AM13:AM47")
            If AName = CLng(Code) And AName.Offset(0, -1) = user Then ' Use this for passcode numbers only
                MsgBox "Welcome Back: – " & user & " " & Code
                AddData.Value = user
                AddData.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
                Current.Value = user
                result = 1
                MainMenuAdmin.Show
                Unload OpeningWindow
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next AName
    End If

    If user <> "" And Not IsNumeric(user) And Code <> "" And IsNumeric(Code) Then
        For Each PName In Sheet3.Range("E13:E47")
            If PName = Code And PName.Offset(0, -1) = user Then ' Use this for passcode numbers only
                MsgBox "Welcome Back: – " & user & " " & Code
                AddData.Value = user
                AddData.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
                Current.Value = user
                result = 1
                MainMenuUser.Show
                Unload OpeningWindow
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next PName
    End If

    If result = 0 Then
        Trial = Trial + 1
        If Trial < 3 Then msg = MsgBox("Wrong password, please try again", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, TitleStr)
        OpeningWindow.UsernameTextbox.SetFocus
        If Trial = 3 Then
            msg = MsgBox("Wrong password, the form will close…", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, TitleStr)
            ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        End If
    End If
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
 MsgBox "An Error has Occurred " & vbCrLf & "The error number is: " _
 & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
 "Please notify the administrator"
 End Sub
```

`

and this is the code I'm using that shows the userform before having access to the workbook:

`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWindow.Visible = False
    OpeningWindow.Show
    Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

`

How this basically works is the code reads through a list on sheet3 for the corresponding username and password thats being entered and then allows me access to the workbook if the password that's inputed matches the database of its corresponding username. My theory is because the worksheet (while the work book is technically open) is hidden still, the code can't find the row/columns where the username list is, but i could be wrong (hence why i'm asking here). Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Delete    `On Error GoTo errHandler:` and see where exactly the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `Sheet3.Rows.Count` instead of `Rows.Count`.

As far as this is the only place you are using `Rows`, it should be the one making the error.

Comment: Wow. That was... really simple. I'm relatively new to the world of coding (especially with excel) so that was really helpful. Thank you!